# Error installing google wavebox in ubuntu linux server

Tags: linux, clone

I am trying to configure and instance of http://waveinabox.net/ . I have been facing an error while installing wave box in linux server

operating system  : Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

I have used commands from this site  : http://www.waveprotocol.org/wave-in-a-box/setting-up

```
  $sudo apt-get install mercurial ant default-jdk mongodb eclipse
  $mkdir wave-development
  $cd wave-development
```

Problem starts when I type this line

```
  $hg clone https://wave-protocol.googlecode.com/hg/ wave-protocol
```

I am getting error (error is: No command `clone` found )

I am not used to linux commands much, can anybody tell me what could be the issue. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you need to install mercurial - sudo apt-get install mercurial
after installing try it.